# Are there python bindings for the lookback api?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Are there python bindings that are available for the Rally lookback API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any specific REST Toolkits for Lookback from Rally. Not sure how useful it is, but the following:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-Python-LookbackConnectionHelper

Is a very basic Python `requests` connection wrapper/helper for python that I've used from time-to-time.